# how to extract some css rule from an external stylesheet that's expecting a different layout

Tags: css, sass

For an organization I work for, there is a common stylesheet that all web applications are supposed to use.

For example, they expect some elements to be in `thead.table-sortable th.table-sortable-sorted-down a:after` to add a sorting icon. Now, in an Angular application, I use a component library (primeng) that has a simple element that just has the class `.pi-sort-up` for the same thing.

How can I map / copy /use part of the organization css into my application's css, to just copy the interesting stuff without requiring the complicated nesting on component (which I have no real control on anyway)?

We could use css, sass, or even dynamically generate css rules in javascript. I'd prefer avoiding changing the DOM at runtime for all matching components, as it could be quite dynamic.

EDIT: A build-time solution (e.g. with sass) isn't the preferred way, but could be acceptable if nothing else.

Comment: Sounds like an over-engineered solution. Why not just copy the rules you want into your Angular app?

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo the company style is maintained by another team and is subject to change. They imposed us to use their structure (e.g. for tables), so that an update on the css is reflected immediately in all applications. I don't like it, but it's the way it is. The official solution is: don't use component libraries. Any idea on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If the company style sheet is *readonly* for you, there is not much you can do at all. You will have to load the whole document wherever you need some parts of it. A possible "workaround" to avoid that would be to write a backend program (in PHP or node.js) which opens the company style document and looks only for a specific CSS rule which it then copies and pastes to some other style document.

However, this approach would be very dynamic as well and you needed to execute the backend script with each request, for the original company style sheet could change always... If your company could agree, you should use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS and define a structure for the company style, dividing it into several documents that can be loaded on purpose.

Comment: It's not that I don't want the company style sheet, but rather that I want some additional rules, in order to map the components from the component library I use to the company style. e.g. some additional css to say that .pi-sort-up = thead.table-sortable th.table-sortable-sorted-down a:after